# How to prevent odoo from creating duplicated field?

Tags: python, sql, constraints, odoo, odoo-12

I create a method _sql_constraints in Odoo 12 to make product name which is computed field to be unique and I didn't get any validation on duplicated names?

here is the code

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, Warning, ValidationError
from statistics import mean
class autopart(models.Model):

_inherit = 'product.template'


@api.multi
@api.depends('item','dsc', 'drc', 'org','car','model', 'manf','year')
def naming(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.year:
            rec.name = " ".join(
                [rec.item or "", rec.drc or "", rec.dsc or "",
                 rec.org or "", rec.manf or "", rec.car or "",
                 rec.model or "", rec.year or ""
                 ])
        else:
            rec.name = " ".join(
                [rec.item and rec.item or "", rec.drc and rec.drc or "", rec.dsc and rec.dsc or "",
                 rec.org and rec.org or "", rec.manf and rec.manf or "", rec.car and rec.car or "",
                 rec.model or "",
                 ])

_sql_constraints = [
     ('model', 'unique(model)', ' model must be unique'),]

name = fields.Char(string="Name", compute=naming, store=True, required=True,)
item = fields.Char( store=True, string="Item", ondelete='restrict', required=False, )
dsc = fields.Char(store=True, string="Description", ondelete='restrict', required=False)
drc = fields.Char(store=True, string="Direction", ondelete='restrict', required=False)
org = fields.Char(store=True, string="Origin", ondelete='restrict', required=True)
manf = fields.Char(store=True, string="Origin manufacture", ondelete='restrict', required=False)
car = fields.Char(store=True, string="Car", ondelete='restrict', required=False,)
year = fields.Char(store=True, string="Year", required=False, ondelete='restrict')
model = fields.Char(string="Model", ondelete='restrict', required=True,  default='')
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is duplicated products in the database, the following constraint will not work because of a `psycopg2.IntegrityError`.

```
_sql_constraints = [
     ('uniq_name', 'unique(name)', 'Name must be unique'),
]
```

**Log**:

```
ERROR stackoverflow odoo.sql_db: bad query: ALTER TABLE "product_template" ADD CONSTRAINT "product_template_uniq_name" unique(name)  
ERROR: could not create unique index "product_template_uniq_name"  
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(   US   K360) is duplicated.

WARNING stackoverflow odoo.schema: Table 'product_template': unable to add constraint 'product_template_uniq_name'!
If you want to have it, you should update the records and execute manually:
ALTER TABLE "product_template" ADD CONSTRAINT "product_template_uniq_name" unique(name) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/sql.py", line 138, in add_constraint
    cr.execute(query1)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/sql_db.py", line 148, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/sql_db.py", line 225, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "product_template_uniq_name"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(   US   K360) is duplicated.
```

Instead, you can use a [Python constrains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.constrains).

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change with this,
You want the product name should be unique for that check out the **_sql_constraints** and check also the field declaration with **compute**.

```
_sql_constraints = [
('name_uniq', 'unique (name)', "Name already exists !"),
]
```

name = fields.Char(string="Name", compute="naming", store=True, required=True,)

Thanks